# Roslaunch arguments problems

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm trying to make a simple roslaunch file. The problems are the arguments. My node needs 3 arguments, I don't understand how i should write the launch file.

this command works fine: rosrun teste_aruco ros_aruco2 live ~/catkin_ws/src/ros_aruco/data/logitech_9000_intnsics.yml 0.127

How do I turn this into a roslaunch? I'm trying something like this:

```
<launch>
    <node name="teste_aruco" pkg="teste_aruco" type="ros_aruco2" args="live ~/catkin_ws/src/ros_aruco/data/logitech_9000_intrinsics.yml 0.127" />
</launch>
```

And this does not work...Anyone knows how to do this currectly?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/204658/roslaunch-arguments-problems/) by [End-Effector](https://answers.ros.org/users/7606/end-effector/) on ROS Answers with karma: 162 on 2015-03-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure about that but I think you can't use the "~" to define your home directory in a launch file. You could try something like:

```
<launch>
    <node name="teste_aruco" pkg="teste_aruco" type="ros_aruco2" args="live $(find ros_aruco)/data/logitech_9000_intrinsics.yml 0.127" />
</launch>
```

or use the full path to the .yml file.

---

Originally posted by [JorgeArino](https://answers.ros.org/users/20071/jorgearino/) with karma: 96 on 2015-03-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [End-Effector](https://answers.ros.org/users/7606/end-effector/) on 2015-03-10**:
You are the man!